# Is it possible to make a table with 5 tiles that looks like this

Tags: html, css, html-table

[image]

I cannot have alternatives such as 9 tiles and having inactive corner tiles or such...

Comment: Doesn't look much like a table to me.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, make an effort of your own and come back with that if you can't make it work.